# Writing taken picture slow

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I'm using [this method](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html) to take pictures in my app, however in `onActivityResult` I try to load the picture like this:

```
if (requestCode == TAKE_PICTURE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath);
            // Do something with it
```

However the bitmap is null, if I set a breakpoint at that spot the image can be loaded normaly, however if I implement the procedure in a new app it's always ready to be loaded. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you tried doing it like in the tutorial ?:
 Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");

Comment: please do some debugging ... like `Log.d(TAG, "path: \"" + mCurrentPhotoPath + "\"");` ... i bet that you would get `TAG: path:"null"`

Comment: From what I've read, the bitmap from extras is merely a 300x300 thumbnail

Comment: *merely a 300x300 thumbnail* ... or even on some devices is null

Comment: the path that you've asked me to log points to an image that exists, and is indeed a valid picture. However, when the onActivityResult is called, the image seems to be incomplete, while in the demo app in which I first implemented this had the image written and available at that point

Comment: [could you post `launchMode` of YOUR activity from the manifest which calls `dispatchTakePictureIntent`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16592623/onactivityresult-getting-called-as-soon-as-camera-intent-is-sent)

Comment: I did not set a launchMode

Comment: perhaps worth noting, the onActivityResult is not called after sending the intent, but after actually taking the picture.

Comment: Are you getting null pointer exception or any other?

Comment: the value of bitmap is null, no exception is thrown whatsoever.